# R quantile function 0% interpretation

Tags: r, quantile

I am using the `quantile` function and I am wondering what is the proper interpretation of the 0% quantile.

Is this function computing intervals (e.g. 0-25%, ...) or the specific values (e.g. the median, ...)?

```
> quantile(x <- rnorm(1001))
         0%         25%         50%         75%        100% 
-2.79229420 -0.69018867  0.09633718  0.78119303  2.75848870
```

Could someone explain me what the `0%` and `100%` mean?

Comment: `0%` and `100%` are respectively the minimum and maximum values, while the others three represents the first quartile (0.25), the median (0.5) and the third quartile (0.75)

Comment: so, would the `1%` probability then give the `1%`? Not an interval right? Thanks a lot